# How to implement an additional non-wcf service contract interface in a WCF service contract interface implementation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-data-services

I'm creating a WCF service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IContractManagementServices
{    
    ...
}
```

and i want the contract implementation to also implement another interface:

```
public interface ILogin
{
    bool GetLoginCredential(String LoginID, String Password);
}
```

For example:

```
public class ContractManagementServices : IContractManagementServices, ILogin
{
    ...
}
```

But I am getting an error.

Comment: Try if you can use iOC (Dependency Injection) for that.

Comment: i'm using ContractManagementServices : IContractManagementServices, Ilogin but getting error

Comment: Though we are powerful, StackOverflow.com has not yet evolved the ability to read minds. If you have an error you must post it otherwise we cannot know what error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
    private ILogin _businessLogic {get; set;}
    public Service()
    {
        if (_businessLogic == null) { _businessLogic = new Login(); }
    }
```

I think it will solve your problem.